# Wordpress, how to make the whole sub-menu dropdown block clickable?

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navbar, navigationbar

I am using the below code to display my menu inside `header.php`

```
 $arg = array(
      'menu' => 'top',
      'theme_location' => 'top',
      'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', );
wp_nav_menu($arg);
```

By adding the right css I was able to display the sub-menu correctly on mouse hover . However, on mouse hover, only the text inside the sub-menu block is clickable and the rest of the sub-menu block is not clickable. Also, the code inside page sources confirm that and it is looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu-top" class="nav navbar-nav" >
 <li>
     <ul class="sub-menu" >
         <li id="menu-item-75" ><a href="http://.....">link text</a> </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, I would like that the whole sub-menu block will be clickable and I am think that if somehow I could put the anchor code outside `<li>...</li>` then it is going to work, something that should looks like this: `<a href=""><li>....</li></a>`. But how?
Kindly Let me know how can I do that just by using `css` or `wp_nav_menu($arg);` or what other alternatives do I have?

Thanks a lot

Comment: While you could in theory change this by CSS by adding for example a pseudo element for a and positioning it over the whole block, this way would be unneccessary complicated and might lead to a lot of problems. I woud suggest you solve the issue with JS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* css Solution */
.sub-menu li {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
 display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to the code you posted?

Comment: This did the job, thanks, 
`.sub-menu li {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
 display: block;
} 
.sub-menu li a {
width: 100%;
height:25px;
display: block;
}
`You can edit your answer to above code and I will accept it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `<a>` tag cover entire its parents width and height:

```
.sub-menu li a{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Note: if this did'nt work, you have also set certain height and width for `li` and `ul` and its deep parents (in pixel or percent) until you make sure that 100% has a clear meaning for this block element.

Comment: That didn't work! and Also, I set ul and li to width 100% and height 100% (or 25px) and that also didn't do anything good!